iPhone 11 Restarts after 3 minutes uptime
My iPhone 11 restarts after three minutes of uptime. Crash logs implicate thermalmonitord for missing sensor data from mic2. I've replaced the side button flex cable assembly twice and also tried to simply reseat its connector onto the motherboard several times. I've also replaced the lightning port flex cable assembly. What else might I try?
From panic-full-2024-09-07-161757.0002.ips:
{"bug_type":"210","timestamp":"2024-09-07 16:17:57.00 -0500","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)","roots_installed":0,"incident_id":"EC7F5A11-22C3-4B78-9F56-09241004AE0B"}
{
"build" : "iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)",
"product" : "iPhone12,1",
"socId" : "8030",
"socRevision" : "11",
"incident" : "EC7F5A11-22C3-4B78-9F56-09241004AE0B",
"crashReporterKey" : "bc2be9331d225556424930b13a3977a3c6e3cfb2",
"kernel" : "Darwin Kernel Version 23.1.0: Tue Oct 10 02:21:48 PDT 2023; root:xnu-10002.42.9~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8030",
"date" : "2024-09-07 16:17:57.65 -0500",
"panicString" : "panic(cpu 2 caller 0xfffffff02aef85a4): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from thermalmonitord (2 induced crashes) \nservice returned not alive with context : is_alive_func returned unhealthy : current 3bfffffffffff, mask 1ffffffffffff, expected 1ffffffffffff. SD: 1 BC: 1 RC: -1 BS: 1, Missing sensor(s): mic2 …"
